# Padding in a mobile version with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, padding

I recently had a problem with the footer of a website using bootstrap

[image]

I would therefore like to have a uniform color background

I understand that the body is due to the padding of 10px, but removing it and applying it to the two main div I have a problem in the smartphone version.

The basic code is this

```
<div id="content">
    ...
</ div>
<footer>
    ... 
</ footer>
```

I would like to solve this problem without resorting to the addition of div in the html code

Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with negative margins and compensate with padding.
Try:

```
footer { 
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Edit: To clarify. You need to put this in your media-query that targets screen smaller than 767px likes this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    footer {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include the media-query. Do you get the same result with that added?